# json tag without starting double quote worked

Tags: json, go, struct

I have a struct with json tags. One of then was without starting double quote. During the testing it did work. I wonder why and is there a tool to catch such typos?

```
type req struct {
    Name        string `json:name"`
}
```

I am on `go1.13 linux/amd64`.

Comment: Use `go vet` to detect such errors.

Comment: @BurakSerdar: I did use `go vet` also. It did not catch either.

Comment: @cpuNram `go vet` should give an error in such cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works as if you would remove the invalid tag completely:

```
type req struct {
    Name string
}
```

Quoting from [`json.Marhsal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal):

> Struct values encode as JSON objects. Each exported struct field becomes a member of the object, using the field name as the object key, unless the field is omitted for one of the reasons given below.

If you have an invalid tag, that counts as no tag, and the field name is used by default.

`go vet` reports tags that do not follow the "convention" outlined at [`reflect.StructTag`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag):

> By convention, tag strings are a concatenation of optionally space-separated key:"value" pairs. Each key is a non-empty string consisting of non-control characters other than space (U+0020 ' '), quote (U+0022 '"'), and colon (U+003A ':'). Each value is quoted using U+0022 '"' characters and Go string literal syntax.

Running it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iK_NYcDlRzt) (which also runs `go vet`):

```
./prog.go:9:2: struct field tag `json:name"` not compatible with reflect.StructTag.Get: bad syntax for struct tag value
Go vet exited.

{"Name":"john"} <nil>
```